# Bash multiple ors don't work with negatives

Tags: bash

I have a code bit like this which works just fine;

```sh
if [ "$1" == "something1" ] || [ "$1" == "something2" ] || [ "$1" == "something3" ]; then
    echo "Result is $1"
    # do stuff here if $1 is not equals to one of the above "somethings"
fi
```

```sh
$ ./script.sh something2
Result is something2
```

However, when I change the equal operators (`==`) into not equals (`!=`) then it simply doesn't work anymore.

Example:

```sh
if [ "$1" != "something1" ] || [ "$1" != "something2" ] || [ "$1" != "something3" ]; then
    echo "Result is $1"
    # do stuff here if $1 is not equals to one of the above "somethings"
fi
```

```sh
$ ./script.sh something2
Result is something2
```

It shouldn't have print out the `Result is something2`. I added this to my bash script `#!/bin/bash -x` to see the problem and it says `+ [[ something2 != something1 ]]` when I run the script as `./script.sh something2` so definitely something's wrong here.

I basically want it to continue the if statement if the `$1` is not equals to one of the `somethings` otherwise skip.

What am I missing?

Comment: Generally with the reverse you want to use AND instead of OR. If you read your current line, it reads _if `$1` is not "something1" or `$1` is not "something2"_. Now imagine `$1` equals "something2" then _$1 is not "something1"_ is by default true. So the condition you write will always be true. You should convert your `||` into `&&`

Comment: check again your input/output and the conditions in each case. Whatever is inside the if block gets executed in both cases input ("something1"  , "something2") and with both `==` and `!=` versions. And BTW the output in your second case should be `Result is something2` instead (I tested on my side)

Comment: [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: @KamilCuk, a bit heavy on the stomach, but yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.

```
if [ "$1" != "something1" ] && [ "$1" != "something2" ] && [ "$1" != "something2" ]; then
    echo "Result is $1"
    # do stuff here if $1 is not equals to one of the above "somethings"
fi
```

Reason is even though one OR condition fails in your example, other OR conditions are true and the commands inside the if is executed.