# Display message when variable is not a valid filename or directory

Tags: bash, validation

I want to display a message when the variable `fl` is not a valid filename or directory.
Seems as though there is a problem with the construct below.

```
if [[ ! -f "$fl" || ! -d "$fl" ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "$fl: File or Directory does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: `||` should be `&&`

Comment: You can just use `-e`, it tests any kind of directory entry.

Comment: You want `&&`, not `||` (or better yet, use `-e` to see if there's *something* by that name, instead of separately testing `-f` and `-d`). See ["Bash multiple ors don't work with negatives"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858793/bash-multiple-ors-dont-work-with-negatives), ["Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true), and more generally [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: You may want this: `if ! [[ -f $fl || -d $fl ]]; then`...

Comment: @Poati `-a` can be ambiguous (because it also means "and"); see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434441/why-does-negated-file-existence-check-in-bash-return-weird-results-in-case-of-ex). Use `-e` to check for existence of filesystem objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ ! -e $fl ]; then
  printf '%s\n' "$fl: File or Directory does not exist"
fi
```

If you give it a filename remember to include the extension

Comment: What is the difference between `-a` and `-e` exactly?

Comment: The -a and -e seem to do tho same thing.  Redundancy that seems it is there to stay.